# Изображение SVG внутри круга

Tags: html, html5, svg

Я хочу создать круг, внутри которого находится  изображение. Я уже пробовал использовать `pattern` или `filter`, но ни один из них не дает ожидаемого результата.

Ниже приведен код:

```html
<svg id="graph" width="100%" height="400px">

  <!-- filter -->
  <filter id = "born1" x = "0%" y = "0%" width = "100%" height = "100%">
      <feImage xlink:href = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/people-professions/512/Baby-512.png"/>
  </filter>
  <circle id = "born" class = "medium" cx = "5%" cy = "20%" r = "5%" fill = "white" stroke = "lightblue" stroke-width = "0.5%" filter = "url(#born1)"/>
  
  <!-- pattern -->
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0"  height="100%" width="100%">
      <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/people-professions/512/Baby-512.png"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <circle id = "sd" class = "medium" cx = "5%" cy = "40%" r = "5%" fill = "white" stroke = "lightblue" stroke-width = "0.5%" fill="url(#image)"/>
</svg>
```

Моя цель - сохранить круг и создать фоновое изображение внутри него, что-то вроде атрибута `CSS`  `background-image`.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG image inside circle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29442833/7394871) от участника  [@Bla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003216/bla).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442833/svg-image-inside-circle/29446024#29446024

Comment: В комментариях три года назад выражали сомнение будет ли использоваться SVG. Используется и [поддержка расширяется](https://caniuse.com/?search=svg%20smil). В Chrome убрали depricate, так как до сих пор не нашли полноценной замены для SVG. Данный вопрос по ассоциации и ответ довольно простые, но актуальные и этот прием (изображение в круге) широко используется .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pattern` будет работать. Вам просто необходимо указать размер `<image>`, так как в отличии от `HTML`, SVG-изображения по умолчанию имеют ширину и высоту отличающуюся от нуля.
Кроме того, если вы хотите, чтобы изображение масштабировалось вместе с кругом, то вам следует указать `viewBox` для `pattern`.

```html
<svg id="graph" width="100%" height="400px">

  <!-- pattern -->
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%"
             viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <image x="0%" y="0%" width="512" height="512" xlink:href="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/people-professions/512/Baby-512.png"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
    
  <circle id="sd" class="medium" cx="5%" cy="40%" r="5%" fill="url(#image)" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="0.5%" />
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29446024/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: А правда, что Chrome хочет отказаться от поддержки SMIL? Вроде ведь уже внедренная технология.

Comment: @ labris Chrome  Временно отложил  отказ  поддержки SMIL ещё в августе прошлого года. Было очень бурное обсуждение в блоге разработчиков Chrome. Пока отложили, но надеюсь, что как всегда, нет ничего более постоянного, чем временное

Comment: Я думала вообще smil похоронили, радует что отложили, хотя поддержка и сомнительная, но для чего-нибудь на codepen в самый раз